# Which is faster for filtring a set of data, a select query or a loop?

Tags: java, mysql, select

Let's say that I have a round 10000 lines in MySql database and I want to calculate multiple values(sum. median, average...).

- Which Is is faster, fetch all the 10000 with a simple SQL query and iterate over it using Java and do the calculation or perform directly SQL queries (select sum(..); select count(*)...) ? and is it possible to do only one query that returns the wanted values ?

**EDIT**

- Is there any metric/statistics on the subject ?
- The data can be fetched by joining 2 or 3 tables

Thanks

Comment: not sure there'd be much of a difference in efficiency, but if you can achieve what you want using straight up SQL, I'd recommend doing so.

Comment: Why do you need database then? Store the data in plain text file and do everything in Java.

Comment: "and is it possible to do only one query that returns the wanted values ?" --- one query isn't a silver bullet. Actually there is no reason to want to have a single query for everything. It's like to want to have all your files to be of 1 line.

Comment: @zerkms the data can be fetched from joining tables...so the the plain text file is not an option

Comment: @Moh: from your question it's not obvious that you want to use joins. It's clear that you want to select everything and perform any manipulations right in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends

Most people here said it is faster because it is closer to the data etc.

However it is not necessary true.

For example, if the filtering criteria is complicated, and if number of result is close to total number of record, and if the DB machine is not super fast while your app being super slow, in such case having DB doing the simple job (getting all records) and do the work in your application can be much faster instead.  (I haven't even mentioned the low scalability of DB, which there are more scenario that may cause filtering in DB slower than in app)

So, there is no rule of thumb.

My suggestion is, put simple and straight-forward filtering/aggregation in DB, let the DB does the work it is good at.  If you need extra complication calculations for filtering, do it in application code (and perform on the DB-filtered result).

Answer (score 4):

Using **MySQL** functions is **better and faster option** than writing a code in **Java**. **This is because MySQL functions will be more closer to the data than Java.** Also database(MySQL) functions are extremely optimized for such functions.

If you use java, then you would load that much data in the memory first before applying any logic.

Answer (score 1):

MySql queries will be faster and also save a lot of memory and CPU time too. Its general logic.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there will be exceptions but in general it's best to have the database engine do data filtering, aggregation, sorting etc.  Databases are designed to handle this stuff.